# How to include php script into header for specific page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my script to load only in one certain post page in my blog.

Example page: www.name.com/this-is-cool-post/

How can i call my script if for example my script is in another .php file?

```
<?php if(is_page('this-is-cool-post')){ ?>
      <?php include("myscript.php"); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

this is not working for me and i don't know where to problem is :S

Comment: tip: you don't have to keep jumping in/out of php mode if all of the lines are php. `<?php ALL OF THE CODE ?>` would be sufficient, instead of `<?php ...?><?php ...?><?php ...?>`

Comment: tnx, for the tip. still searching for solution :P

Comment: If that statement returns `true`, it includes the script as it is in that file, into the current code, so it depends on what's inside it. Are there functions you want to use? Content to display? Variables you want to use?

Comment: some functions + content

Comment: If the file is included, you can use those functions after a successful include like any other function. As for content (that is output in that file), that would be displayed directly where that include was called.

Comment: You can check if it actually enters that `if`-block by putting `echo "inside!";` inside it too. Also, you need to be sure that the path to your script is correct - error-reporting would tell you that: Take a look at [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and 
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: **is not working** is very common there may be thousand of reasons for this. You should be very specific with some errors message or code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the location of your script.

If you work on a theme, try to include your script like this

```
include get_template_directory() . "/path_to_ur_script/script.php";
```

I hope that help u.

Comment: How you can be so sure that it is about theme ? :D Well `get_template_directory_uri()` will return the URL. You need path to include PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most programmatic way of doing it, but how about creating a custom blog post template, call it blog-specific.php or whatever you want, add the following to the top of it:

```
<?php
/*
Single Post Template: [Temp Name]
Description: Description of template
*/
?>
```

Then add your script (`<?php include("myscript.php"); ?>`) only to this template:

You should then be able to change the template of a particular post in the Single Post Template dropdown option when editing a post:

[image]